How to capture an output stream from a webrtc server and send it to a django server
I am using webrtc to create a web call service that runs on django server.
When 'a' and 'b' communicate, I want to send the voice stream of a directly to the server of b, modify the voice stream using Python library and model, and output it to b.
Is this possible?
When I looked it up, all I had to do was capture the audio being played on the web audio app and send it to the server. I was wondering if there are any other solutions!
I want to know how to intercept the output stream and modify it on the django server and then output only this modification stream.
